# Table hasOne relation not being created

Tags: laravel-5.3

I have a `tables` table with the model defined like so:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Table extends Model
{
    public function location()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Location');
    }
}
```

And I have a `locations` table with a `table_id` column, and the model defined like so:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Location extends Model
{
    public function table()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Table');
    }
}
```

I have seeded the database with a sample location, which has an `id` of `1`. Inside my controller, inside a `DB::transaction` block, I run the following code:

```
$table = new Table;
$location = Location::findOrFail(1);
$table->location()->save($location);
$table->saveOrFail();
```

This code runs without error, however, when I look at the database, the `table_id` column for my location is still empty. What am I doing wrong?

I have also tried the following, to no avail:

```
$table = new Table;
$location = Location::findOrFail(1);
$table->saveOrFail();
$location->table()->associate($table);
```

Only the following seems to work:

```
$table = new Table;
$table->save();
$location = Location::findOrFail(1);
$location->table_id = $table->id;
$location->save();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it the opposite way. Try the following:

```
$table = new Table;
$location = Location::findOrFail(1);
$location->table()->associate($table);
$location->save();
```

What you really need to do is associate the foreign key of the instance to a new object, and the foreign key is in the `Location` model.